# Spring security authentication against DB

Tags: spring, spring-security

In Spring I am trying to authenticate against DB .it is successful using this config:

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from user where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from user u, user_roles ur 
          where u.id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
```

but I can't login until I add a row in user_roles for each user to specify ROLE_USER at least...is there a way to grant ROLE_USER to all users without adding a record in DB?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can return that role by default in your **authorities-by-username-query**. For example the following query will return in the first part of the union, the **user/role** pairs that exist in your database (the query that you already had) and the second part of the union will return for each user a pair **user/ROLE_USER** therefore every user now will have the role **ROLE_USER** even if that does not exist in user_roles table

```
select u.username, ur.authority from user u, user_roles ur 
          where u.id = ur.user_id and u.username =?
union
select u.username, 'ROLE_USER' from user u
```